# Matplotlib - x-axis labels issue?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, label, axes

I'm trying to add labels to the x-axis of my graph at certain points, like so:

```py
  for i in range(len(chapterPosition)):
    plt.axvline(x = chapterPosition[i], label='{}'.format(chapterList[i]),color = 'black', linestyle = ":")
    list3.append([chapterPosition[i],chapterList[i]])
    plt.xticks([chapterPosition[i]],[chapterList[i]])
    ax1.legend()
```

however, only the very index in ChapterPosition and chapterList (they are the same length) plots, and I'm not sure why, I wanted to plot all of them on the x-axis.
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you move `ax1.legend()` outside the for loop? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't fix anything

Comment: Provide a code which we can run and generate the plot. Currently, we can't guess what is the problem and what is the data

Comment: Did you mean to write `plt.xticks(chapterPosition,chapterList)` and put that outside the loop?